# How to grant Google compute engine instance access to a cloud storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-16.04, gcsfuse

I have a compute engine instance (Ubuntu 16.04) and a storage bucket both in the same project.

I want to mount the storage on the compute instance. I found some resources on this page: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse.

I already installed `gcsfuse` on the instance and created a directory to mount the storage like this:

```
cd $HOME
mkdir storage
```

Then I mounted the storage using the `gcsfuse` command:

```
gcsfuse storage-bucket storage/
```

According the `gcsfuse` output everything looks solid, but when I try to create a test file like:

```
touch storage/test.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
touch: cannot touch 'storage/test.txt': Input/output error
```

I'm kinda stuck at the moment, what else should I try?

Comment: Check your scope for the instance to make sure it has Cloud Storage access.  You may also need to use a service account to access the bucket, depending on its permissions.

Comment: Use the `--foreground` flag when mounting to get errors printed to stderr. If that's not enough detail, try also `--debug_fuse`.

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/190#issuecomment-247928549) and [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/185#issuecomment-243660889) that were resolved by explicitly supplying the `--key-file` parameter when mounting the bucket. Maybe it'll help?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everyone for the support, meanwhile based on this article I managed to set it up for me:

https://www.assistanz.com/mount-google-cloud-storage-bucket-linux/

Also when I created the instance I set the **Access scopes** to **Allow full acces to all Cloud APIs** and now it works like a charm!